# Does "bend your knees, please" have the same meaning as "squat down, please"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

Do these two sentences imply the same action?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not at all!

[image: Kneeling down]

"Bend your knees, please!" means that the speaker asks the listener to stay in a postition where one or both knees are on the ground. This position is often interpreted as an act of praying and submission (compare Romeo & Juliet).

[image: Squatting down]

"Squat down, please!" means that the speaker requests the listener to lower his/her butt to sit like a frog. This position is often interpreted as an act of performing Yoga and Quadriceps Exercises. In some of the Asian countries, there are squat toilets where a squatting down position is needed!

Comment: Mithun - WOW!!! Thank you for the nicely illustrated answer!

Comment: I disagree *strongly* with the first part of this answer. To me "bend the knee" is an *archaic* expression for "kneel in submission". "Bend your knees please" absolutely does not suggest this to me: it means literally, "bend your knees" - i.e. cause them not to be straight. It might indeed mean "squat down", but to me probably means rather less bending. It does not suggest "kneel down". The context I would expect to hear it is something like "Please lower your head or shoulders so that I can reach them".

Comment: @brilliant -> Sure! :) I hope I made you understand the meaning of the two phrases.

Comment: @Fine -> Don't go so deep to grasp the actual context as the questioner needs a basic comprehension. But, I must agree with you because there is a possibility that the asker may misunderstand the first phrase by insisting the context of what I explained for a situation where the context what you suggested would be needed.

Comment: @Mithun "*I must agree with you because there is a possibility that the asker may misunderstand the first phrase by insisting the context of what I explained for a situation where the context what you suggested would be needed*" - I asked this question without having any context at hand, I just happened to hear both phrases and wasn't sure if they meant the same thing. My main point here is this: Would you say "Bend your knees, please" to someone if you want him to squat down?

Comment: @brilliant -> Nope! As Mr.Fine said, the phrase "Bend your knees, please" will not mean to squat down. Because, if the speaker really intends you to squat down, he will be very specific. So, his choice will be the second phrase. In the other hand, I have heard pastors saying "Bend your knees and praise the lord" and "Bend your knees and worship" many times. So, the natural meaning of the first phrase is to get on your knees for prayer and submission. Follow the link http://chosengeneration.cc/2009/10/12/who-is-your-god/ and find for the phrase "bend your knees". The author meant it to pray!

Comment: @brilliant -> Sure! :)

Answer (score 3):

No.

Squatting down generally requires you to have some part of the body which is above the knees when standing erect to be below the knees.

Bending the knees, while this action can include squatting down, only requires the knees to be bent slightly. For example, some people recommend bending the knees to keep the circulation of the blood in the legs unconstricted, but this does not require squatting down.

Answer (score 1):

The first may be addressing someone in a supine or sitting position, the second only someone standing.